# Having Trouble connecting MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern, react-fullstack

0

I'm Following a MERN Stack tutorial from Udemy and I'm trying to connect mongodb with mongoose. The code I have configures is here:

(db.js)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db);

    console.log('MongoDB Connect...');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    //Exit process with falure
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

(server.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

//connect database
connectDB();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API Running'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

(package.json)

```
{
  "name": "devconnect",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Social Network for Developers",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server"
  },
  "author": "Jason Thomas",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.2.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.3.1",
    "gravatar": "^1.8.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.9",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

After I enter [npm run server]This is my error message

```
Server started on port 5000
Password contains an illegal unescaped character
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I cant figure this out and I know its something simple, What am I doing wrong, How do I fix this?

Best Regards
& Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same folder structure, you should have a config/default.json like this, containing the string you copy-pasted from your mongoDB cluster connection settings:

```
{
  "mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://username:<password>@devconnector-clusterid.mongodb.net/somethingSomething?retryWrites=true",
  "jwtSecret": "secret",
  "githubClientId": "",
  "githubSecret": ""
}
```

**Be sure to remove the characters < > when you enter your password.**

All the files for the new course here - [Devconnector 2.0](https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector_2.0) In the [older version](https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector) of the course it's config/keys.js .

Comment: I think that really worked!!!! This is what I get now:  ```Server started on port 5000
(node:7320) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
MongoDB Connect...```

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake initially. In the MongoDB URI link remove the '{}' on